# Shiny datatable: Format row depending on two conditions

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

Currently I have this:

```
datatable(SignalDataFrame,selection = 'single', options=list(dom='ft')) %>%
    #datatable(ResultDF, options=list(dom='ft')) %>%
      formatStyle(
        '200d MA',
        backgroundColor = styleInterval(0, c('#e6b8b7', '#d8e4bc'))
      ) %>%
      formatStyle(
        '50v200d MA',
        backgroundColor = styleInterval(0, c('#e6b8b7', '#d8e4bc'))
      ) %>%
      formatDate(c(3,5,6), "toLocaleDateString")
    })
```

As you see, style interval only formats values <0 in red and values >0 in green. I however want only to format cells in red respective in green for which their respective date is "younger" than 10 days.

For example column 200dMA (being column 2) should be only red if the value in this cell is <0 and the date in column 3 is younger than 10 days. And it should be green if the value is >0 and the date in column 3 is younger than 10 days.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an extra column `check` to `SignalDataFrame` that checks columns `200d MA` and `50v200d MA`. Than, use it at `formatStyle` and hide it with `visible`.

Comment: But can you show the formatStyle command to format column '50v200d MA' based on the value of the new column check?

Comment: This documentation shows how to do that: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html